# Notification cron in PHP for iphone Application

Tags: php, ios, cron, apple-push-notifications

I can send notification manually as following code.

```
<?php

// Device token:
$deviceToken = 'xxxxxx';

$passphrase = 'xxxxx';
$badge = 1;

// Displays alert message here:
$message = 'Match Found!';


$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert',      '/Users/Documents/iOS_Application_Developement/new/APNSPHP/ApnsPHP-master/ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
'alert' => $message,
'badge' => $badge,
'sound' => 'default'
);


// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)).$payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);

?>
```

I also had a APNS PHP integration.but in that there are so many files.For my purpose only one file is useful.

Now i want to run this php script when certain occurrence take place in iOS through my API. So i can write this code under some function and call that function when certain occurrence take place. So what is the best way to do it? and how can i achieve notification cron that run after every 5 minutes?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set up cron job in php(for iOS application)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184931/how-to-set-up-cron-job-in-phpfor-ios-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a cron entry in `/etc/cron.d/`

```
 */5 * * * * root cd /path_to_your_script/ && php your_script.php >> /var/some.log &2>&1
```

Comment: can you describe in detail..I can not understand what is written here?

Comment: this is an entry in a cron file. `*/5` means run every 5 minutes. the other * stands for hours, day of the week, day of the month, month etc. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron for full details.

Comment: I want to implement at API level for iOS application.Not at liux side.So this is not an answer.